# My git repository has the local and remote origins mixed up

Tags: git

Suppose I have a local non-bare git repo in /home/myacct/whatever.

Somehow I'm in a situation where /home/myacct/whatever/.git/config thinks this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
    mirror = true
    url = /home/myacct/whatever
```

All my branches say that they are tracking branches to the remote origin, when what I really want is just a simple local repository with local branches.

Is there a simple way to fix this?

I think I can guess how this happened. I back up my repo's using git clone, and I may have restored a messed up local repo from the cloned version. This may possibly have led to this situation. I just caught this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration has an internal conflict:

```
core.bare = false
```

and yet:

```
remote.origin.mirror = true
remote.origin.fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
```

Since you want it to be non-bare, leave the `core.bare` setting alone, but delete the `remote.origin.mirror` setting entirely and fix the `remote.origin.fetch` setting:

```
git config --unset remote.origin.mirror
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

This is the setup you would have with an ordinary, non-bare repository; at this point you can run `git fetch origin` to create all the normal remote-tracking branches.  If you have local branches that are copies of the remote branches, they're harmless but you can delete them in the usual way.  If you have other references you want to discard, you can delete these with `git update-ref -d`, but this is a little bit trickier, and probably there are none to worry about anyway.